# How to xor char within string and add to List?

Tags: scala

In this code where I'm attempting to xor the corresponding characters of two strings :

```
val s1 = "1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c";
val s2 = "686974207468652062756c6c277320657965";
val base64p1 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new BigInteger(s1, 16).toByteArray())
val base64p2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new BigInteger(s2, 16).toByteArray())
val zs : IndexedSeq[(Char, Char)] = base64p1.zip(base64p2);
val xor = zs.foldLeft(List[Char]())((a: List[Char] , b: (Char, Char)) =>  ((Char)((b._1 ^ b._2))) :: a)
```

produces error :

```
Char.type does not take parameters
[error]         val xor = zs.foldLeft(List[Char]())((a: List[Char] , b: (Char, Char)) =>  ((Char)((b._1 ^ b._2))) :: a)
```

How to xor the corresponding string char values and add them to List ?

Comment: Why do you go to base64? Isn't it ok to use `(BigInt(s1, 16) ^ BigInt(s2, 16)).toString(16).toList`? What list or string should be the result of xoring in your example?

Comment: You can use `map` instead of `foldLeft`.

Comment: @Kolmar hex decoding 1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c and xor'd with 686974207468652062756c6c277320657965 should produce 746865206b696420646f6e277420706c6179 reference : https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/2

Comment: Yep, `(BigInt(s1, 16) ^ BigInt(s2, 16)).toString(16)` returns just that. You may also need to prepend the result with zeros in the cases when the xors of first digits are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is can be simplified.

```
val xor = base64p1.zip(base64p2).map{case (a,b) => (a^b).toChar}.reverse
```

The result of the XOR op (`^`) is an `Int`.  Just add `.toChar` to change it to a `Char` value.

But it looks like what you really want to do is XOR two large hex values that are represented as strings, and then return the result as a string.  To do that all you need is...

```
val (v1, v2) = (BigInt(s1, 16), BigInt(s2, 16))
f"${v1 ^ v2}%x"  // res0: String = 746865206b696420646f6e277420706c6179
```

Answer (score 1):

You use java casting syntax. In scalla you cast like `var.asInstanceOf[Type]`.

Should be `(b._1 ^ b._2).asInstanceOf[Char]`.